# Boundary conditions of electrostatics

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, maxwell-equations, boundary-conditions

As we have seen that while deriving the boundary conditions in **Griffith's electrodynamics** he stated some conclusions, that were

- **The Perpendicular components of Electric field and Gradient of Potential is discontinuous**
- **Parallel component of E. field and potential is continuous**

While I have no confusion in derivation of these but what I wanted to ask was that what does he meant by  continuous and discontinuous here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply that the limit at any point of the surface, constrained to one side or to other side may be the same (continuous function) or different (discontinuous function).
It is the 3D generalization of the condition on the left and right limit for functions of one variable.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that's exactly what he meant..Thank you so very much.